# Blur screen after installing customised Ubuntu 16-04 in HP DL380 gen10 server

Tags: hybrid-graphics

After Installing Ubuntu 16.04 server edition in HP Proliant DL380 gen10 server monitor displaying Blurred screen.

Same Blur screen on HP Allin one desktop ( ubuntu 16.04 desktop ver )

Pls help

Comment: Have you tried to install an uncustomised version?

Comment: Not yet , customer permitted to test it tomorrow.

Comment: Hi, Today morinig i changed Monitor VGA Cable & kept under observation till End of day no issue .

Comment: As per Desktop is concerned i tried non-customized even 18.04.2 LTS.,  but same flickering issue.

Comment: As per Desktop is concerned i tried non-customized even 18.04.2 LTS.,  but same flickering issue.  desktop details are :- HP ProOne-600-G4-21-S-in-Non-Touch-AIO / Processor :- Intel Core i3-8100CPU@3.60GHz x 4  /  Graphics:- Intel UHD Graphics 630(Coffeelake 3x0 GT2 ) / GNOME:-3.7K.7